# Aggregating View Counts with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my micro-blogging application, the user should be able to see a breakdown of Posts' views in their statistics page. But additionally, they should have a nice total of views across all Posts for simplicity's sake.

EG: If Post #1 has 10 visitors and Post #2 has 5 visitors, they'd see 15 visitors as their total count of visitors across all of their posted content.

I'm aware that I can do a `App\Post::withCount('visitors')->get();` to have each individual post's total views, but what's the best way to aggregate all of those into one total number?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sum function to have the sum of all the visitors

```
App\Post::withCount('visitors')->sum('visitors');
```